# $row['password'] is empty

Tags: php, mysql

im making a social networking website (i will not tell my full idea yet) and i cant get login verification to work.
This is my code:

```
mysql_connect("AHOST", "MYDATABASE", "PRIVACY");
mysql_select_db("u848966676_users");
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['code'];
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * from `users` WHERE `email`='$email' LIMIT 1");
if(!$rs) die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
    $active = 0;
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_row($rs)) {
    $rp = $row['password'];
    $active = $row['active'];
    if($password != $rp) {
        die("<script>alert(\"Password is incorrect.$rp and $password\");</script>");
    }
}
if($active === 0) {
    echo "<script>alert(\"Account has not been verified.\");</script>";
                            } else {
                                $_SESSION['logged'] = true;
                                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                                header("Location: index.php");
                            }
                        } else {
                                echo "<script>alert(\"Account does not exist.\");</script>";
                        }
```

And my problem is that $rp is ""... its literally empty!
But on phpMyAdmin is shows my password...
:(

Comment: Try not to use `mysql_*` functions as they are [deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Please do not use mysql_query, use PDO instead. 
WHAT does SELECT password from `users` WHERE `email`='enteredemail' LIMIT 1 return?

Comment: Are other fields populated?

Comment: Try to print `$rp[0]`

Comment: I tried using $rp[0], it didn't work, it keeps saying its incorrect.

Comment: And the active column works perfectly, its the other one that dosen't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql_fetch_row returns a numeric array, so you should use mysql_fetch_assoc for an assoziative array.

The mysql_ extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future, you should use mysqli_ or (better) PDO if you dont want to change everything later on.

Comment: array(7) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["fname"]=> string(4) "PRIVATE" ["lname"]=> string(6) "PRIVATE" ["email"]=> string(21) "PRIVATE@gmail.com" ["password"]=> string(8) "PRIVATE" ["hash"]=> string(32) "3d36c07721a0a5a96436d6c536a132ec" ["active"]=> string(1) "0" }

Comment: Actually now neither of them work (neither passwod and active)

Comment: So, where is your problem? var_dump shows, in $row['password'] is the password.

Comment: Then you have some problems in other parts of your code, with fetch_assoc you get exactly what you want.